# How to filter pair of rows based on two ordered values

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm working on a French historical census and I'm looking to filter married couples.
In my data, a married couple is a male followed by a demale (**always in this order**). There are also other members.

```
        id <- c(1:10)
        members <- c("male", "male", "female", "male", "female", "male", "children", "cousin", "female", "male") 

        household <- data.frame(id, members)  
        household

        library(dplyr)
        married_couples <- household %>%
          filter(members == "male", lead(members) =="female" )
        married_couples


           id  members
           1     male
           2     male
           3   female
           4     male
           5   female
           6     male
           7 children
           8   cousin
           9   female
          10     male
```

What I want :

```
           id  members
           2     male
           3   female
           4     male
           5   female
```

I tried without succes :

```
library(dplyr)
married_couple <- household %>%
filter(members == "male", lead(members) =="female" )
married_couple
```

Answer (score 1):

To get a pair you also have to `filter` the `lag` values.

```
library(dplyr)

household %>%
  filter(members == "male" & lead(members) =="female" | 
         members == "female" & lag(members) == "male")

#  id members
#1  2    male
#2  3  female
#3  4    male
#4  5  female
```

Same way with `data.table` :

```
library(data.table)
setDT(household)[members == "male" & shift(members, type = "lead") =="female" | 
                 members == "female" & shift(members) =="male"]
```